Structural pattern matching binds already defined variables but treats instance attributes as literals: is this documented anywhere?
PEP 636 - Structural Pattern Matching discusses how pattern matching binds values to variables declared on the go:

match command.split():
    case ["quit"]:
        print("Goodbye!")
        quit_game()
    case ["look"]:
        current_room.describe()
    case ["get", obj]:
        character.get(obj, current_room)

A pattern like ["get", obj] will match only 2-element sequences that have a first element equal to "get". It will also bind obj = subject[1].

If obj already had a value, we might expect the value to be used as if it was a literal, but that doesn't happen. Instead obj is overwritten:
>>> # I'm using Python 3.12. You can copy/paste this straight into iPython
>>> obj = 3
>>> for i in range(5):
...     match i:
...         case obj:
...             print(i)  # Does this print only 3?
0
1
2
3
4
>>> obj
4

This doesn't happen if you specify an instance attribute:
>>> from dataclasses import dataclass
>>> @dataclass
... class Num:
...     x: int
...
>>> num = Num(x=3)
>>> for i in range(5):
...     match i:
...         case num.x:  # does this bind num.x to i???
...             print(i)
...
3

In this second case, num.x is unchanged and is used as if it were a literal.
This isn't mentioned anywhere in PEP 636 that I can see. Where can I read about this subtlety? Was this behaviour introduced after PEP 636 was implemented?
(Note: I think this behaviour is perfectly sensible and good. I'd just like to know if/where it's documented)

Only simple variables are treated specially. Attribute references are not variables.

I've found something in the Python 3.10 release notes that comes close to documenting this: "...named constants must be dotted names to prevent the constant from being interpreted as a capture variable:"

@Barmar I'm looking specifically for some documentation around this.

PEP-636 is just a tutorial. The detailed specification is in PEP-634 and has been merged into the Python documentation

In particular, Capture Patterns specifies the syntax of patterns that capture into variables.

it says that it captures into NAME, which is a single token.

@Barmar perfect. That's exactly what I was looking for. If you'd like to make that the answer to this question, that'd be great.

This is specified in the Capture Patterns section of the documentation of match:

capture_pattern ::=  !'_' NAME


NAME is just a single identifier, so num.x is not included in this syntax. !'_' excludes the special case of _, which is defined as a wildcard pattern in the next section.
